# Nothing but looking around works in Minecraft 1.7.2 and 1.7.4, but it did in previous versions

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Okay, so let me tell you what happens. I can play any version just fine, and I could play with the snapshots before 1.7.2 was fully released. But now, when I try to go into a world or a server, all I can do is look around. None of the buttons will respond, clicking won't respond, but it renders the world around me and I can turn (very slowly) and look at everything. And on servers, the chat shows what it would show when you join the server, but it doesn't update the chat after that.

I don't have any mods installed and I don't use any resource packs. My computer is a Dell Latitude D600 with Windows XP.

This might help: Game ended with bad state (exit code 1073807364)

This may also help: (latest log)

```
[01:10:43] [main/INFO]: Setting user: camosham
[01:10:43] [main/INFO]: (Session ID is token:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)
[01:10:44] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.1
[01:10:47] [Client thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
[01:10:49] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 512x256 textures/blocks-atlas
[01:10:49] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 256x256 textures/items-atlas
[01:10:49] [Client thread/ERROR]: ########## GL ERROR ##########
[01:10:49] [Client thread/ERROR]: @ Post startup
[01:10:49] [Client thread/ERROR]: 1280: Invalid enum
[01:10:53] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Sound engine started
[01:11:19] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting integrated minecraft server version 1.7.4
[01:11:19] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[01:11:20] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for level 0
[01:11:21] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 24%
...
[01:11:41] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 96%
[01:11:42] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 99%
[01:11:43] [Server thread/INFO]: Changing view distance to 8, from 10
[01:11:43] [Server thread/INFO]: camosham[local:E:b5bde434] logged in with entity id 548 at (151.5, 62.0, 252.5)
[01:11:43] [Server thread/INFO]: camosham joined the game
[01:11:47] [Server thread/WARN]: Can't keep up! Did the system time change, or is the server overloaded? Running 3805ms behind, skipping 76 tick(s)
[01:12:04] [Server thread/WARN]: Can't keep up! Did the system time change, or is the server overloaded? Running 2814ms behind, skipping 56 tick(s)
```

Comment: Just to clarify- running pre 1.7.2 versions still works?

Comment: Yes. Pre 1.7.2 versions still work.

Comment: please use better title than "doesn't work"

Comment: also, when does the game end with said bad state? have a look at the console if you start it from the command line, maybe there's a helpful warning/error there

Comment: last time I read something similar like this, it was a corrupted `lwjgl.jar` in `%appdata%\.minecraft\bin`, or even deleting that entire directory (and updating again) for good measure might help you

Comment: That is the only error, and I have to manually close the game or it will not close. I have to press the windows start button on my keyboard to even be able to see my pointer. Also, I'm sorry about my poor wording in the title.

Comment: @camosham No need to apologize, but please be more creative/verbose next time ;)

Comment: Would posting the report of my latest (failed) log be helpful?

Comment: @camosham Yup (please use @someone so they get a notification of your comment btw) - btw you can improve the formatting by marking the text and clicking on the "`{}` code" icon. The messages indeed suggest some OpenGL trouble - the `1280: Invalid enum` sounds like some screen resolution issue. Anyway, did you try deleting/renaming `%appdata%\.minecraft\bin` and re-updating?

Comment: @Zommuter thanks for your helpful tips on formatting and comments. I honestly could not find my bin folder. I am confused as I know how to et to the .minecraft folder, but it isn't in there. I will redownload Minecraft and tell you what happens.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12279/discussion-between-camosham-and-zommuter)

Comment: @camosham Sorry, I was merely passing by and trying to help, I'm currently too low on time for anything beyond that

Comment: I believe it is because there isn't enough ram being filtered into the server.. can I ask how much ram you are actually outputting into the server via the command line when you first start the server? I would also suggest possibly rendering your blocks to a visibility of 3 or 4, 10 is the norm but it runs smoother at the above indicated values.

Comment: @camosham Have you tried a deep clean. Back up all you want to keep; delete every unwanted file&folder and fully uninstall all unwanted/unused programs; defragment and all other clean up processes. Better still if you have all the discs format and have a fresh install. Elevating the laptop by placing toy blocks under the feet can improve the ventilation. The cooler it is the better it will run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mojang has added features into versions 1.7.2 and up that require at least OpenGL 2.1, a large jump from previous requirements. If toggling Advanced OpenGL doesn't help, you'll have to stick to 1.6.4. I think this is definitely the problem after looking up some Dell Latitude computers.

Comment: There is no Advanced OpenGL button in 1.7.4.

Comment: New shaders in 1.7 may cause a need for more advanced graphics cards, maybe try turning down graphics? If that doesnt work, try a forced update to redownload the libraries that minecraft uses

Comment: @camosham It's buried in a couple menus. I'll see later today it you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would honestly consider looking in to a better laptop/desktop. Reason being is that I had a desktop as good as your laptop and from previous experience realized that my windows xp desktop could not cope with the demand of minecraft (Sounds unlikely but true) especially after it went of beta.

As far as any help goes I would suggest changing  all the settings and seeing which one works best for you. I found the setting my render settings at far worked better than when it was at short.

It also seems that you have a really high ping when you are trying to connect to a server which may be the cause to why you can't actually get playing on them.

In a last ditch attempt I suggest that you remove Minecraft from you computer (meaning that you remove all files even the ones in %appdata%) and try re-installing Minecraft from the beginning. However remember to save your world file if there is a lot on there.

Answer (score 0):

If it works fine in SP but not MP, then it's either an issue with the server or a slow internet connection as it appears you have a high ping.

It could be a coincidence that the server started screwing up when they updated to the latest version.